# Cant import numpy nltk or any python modules in terminal or VScode

Tags: python, macos, installation, module, anaconda

In Vscode I have a folder opened with some python files for my ML and frontend for my website plus flask for backend. I am using Macbook Pro M1 2021 version.

In **VScode** terminal I'm in the (base) [my_full_name]@[name's]-MacBook-Pro sroWeb %.
When I run "which python" I get /Users/[my_full_name]/opt/anaconda3/bin/python. When I check list of condo or pip modules installed I see all of the needed modules. However, when I run the code it says numpy not found? If I delete the import it says the next module is not found. It basically cant access any. My python version is Python 3.9.16.

In **Terminal** in the projects directory, when I type "python sroWeb.py" it says zsh: illegal hardware instruction  python app.py.

I have tried reinstalling conda and python, restarting my ide my Mac, Not sure what else to do from here.

Comment: sounds like you need to pip install numpy for the correct version of python. For example, do you have more than 1 version ?  with conda it usually comes shipped with the install.  was it working before ?

Comment: Normal python works without importing any external modules. For example import random works. 

I guess I have three versions of Python:  ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/

3.11 3.6 Current

Comment: I went ahead and deleted both of those using "sudo rm -rf 3.11' and then for 3.6 in case they were causing issues but no, anaconda still cant run.